# Trying to filter django view serializer based on nested model foreignkey

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a django app. Within it, I have 2 models. One of them is a group and the other is a member model. Then member model has a foriegnkey which is the group model. I serialized the models and now I am trying to get the api to to work as I want. I want to be able to call an api that has a group name at the end that is passed as a filter for the members to only return the members of the group name. I have 2 urls. the first one returns all the members of every group while I want the second one to return just the members of a certain group. I have tried a few different things from suggestions but none of them are working. This is the last thing I tried below. I will add my code below.

Models:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=42)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=220)
    user_count = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='group_images/')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ' - ' + self.created_by.username

class Member(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    host = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group.name + ' - ' + self.user.username
```

Urls:

```
path('members/', MemberListView.as_view()),
path('members/<name>', MemberGroupListView.as_view()),
```

views:

```
class MemberListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Member.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer

class MemberGroupListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Member.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = ('user', 'host', 'group')

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(group__name=self.request.query_params.get('name'))
```

the `MemberListView` is working properly but the `MemberGroupListView` is not working.

[image]

---

Update:

added the serialzers:

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'user_count', 'status', 'image', 'created_by')

class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ('group', 'user', 'host')
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: it is returning an empty object when I enter a group name that exists @RedCricket I will add a photo in my original post...

Comment: what does `self.request.query_params.get('name')` return?

Comment: so get rid of the `self.queryset.filter(gorup__name=...)` or how can I test the code you put. @RedCricket

Comment: You need to make sure `self.request.query_params.get('name')` is returning what you expect.  Either print out the value or run your code in the debugger.

Comment: also did you write any serializer classes for your models?  If you are using DRF should probably take advantage of serializers.

Comment: I got it to work.... lol. Thanks @RedCricket

Comment: I think you should get ride of `get_queryset()` and instead pass `self.request.query_params.get('name')` to your serializer via a `context` dict.  And perform your custom query in the serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Url parameters, such as `name` in your case (`path('members/<name>', MemberGroupListView.as_view()),`) are stored in `self.kwargs` in class-based views, so your `get_queryset` should be:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.queryset.filter(group__name=self.kwargs.get('name'))
```